# java : How to see web service description which is easy to understand not WSDL?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I wrote a web service in **.Net** and called it fom my **Android** application. Below is its  description which is easy to understand and provides all necessary information to call service from Android specially e.g. SOAPACTION, content-type etc etc
I could see its content by the link seems like this, Actually .Net interface provices this

> http://192.168.4.47:88/MRMSGlobalService.asmx?op=EstimateTripCost

Now I have another web service written in **Java** whose description is given below this .net service. I could open its description by the link like

> http://localhost:8080/MusicAppService/MusicAppDataService?WSDL

Its description is not so friendly to understand like .Net one, and very very hard to understand, Actually its **WSDL** but I want the one like .Net interface. its written in NetBeans.

I think there could be the way from where we could see the same description like the .net service. As see to this I could not understand how to manipulate the data.

I have to call function **getMusicFileData** but its so so hard to understand what are the parameters and what could be the return data.

Please help. I want the same description of java web service like .net one, which is easy to understand. There should be something in URL; what, this is to find.

**.Net web service**

```
POST /SDApp/MRMSGlobalService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.4.47
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://Itcurves.net/EstimateTripCost"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <EstimateTripCost xmlns="http://Itcurves.net/">
      <NoOfPassengers>int</NoOfPassengers>
      <NoOfWheelChairs>int</NoOfWheelChairs>
      <Distance>double</Distance>
      <Duration>double</Duration>
    </EstimateTripCost>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

---

**Java Webservice**

```
This document had no style information.
<!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.2-b13 (branches/2.2-6964; 2012-01-09T18:04:18+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.6-promoted-b20 JAXWS/2.2 svn-revision#unknown. -->
<!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.2-b13 (branches/2.2-6964; 2012-01-09T18:04:18+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.6-promoted-b20 JAXWS/2.2 svn-revision#unknown. -->
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://Musicpackage/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://Musicpackage/" name="MusicAppDataService">
<wsp:Policy xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702" xmlns:ssp="http://schemas.sun.com/2006/03/wss/server" xmlns:sunwsp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/wsit/policy" wsu:Id="MusicAppDataPortBindingPolicy">
<sp:SymmetricBinding>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:AlgorithmSuite>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:Basic128/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:AlgorithmSuite>
<sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
<sp:Layout>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:Strict/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:Layout>
<sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
<sp:ProtectionToken>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:SecureConversationToken sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:BootstrapPolicy>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:AsymmetricBinding>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:AlgorithmSuite>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:Basic128/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:AlgorithmSuite>
<sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
<sp:InitiatorToken>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:X509Token>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:InitiatorToken>
<sp:Layout>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:Strict/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:Layout>
<sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
<sp:RecipientToken>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/Never">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:RequireIssuerSerialReference/>
<sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:X509Token>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:RecipientToken>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:AsymmetricBinding>
<sp:EncryptedParts>
<sp:Body/>
</sp:EncryptedParts>
<sp:SignedParts>
<sp:Body/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="ReplyTo"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="To"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="From"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" Name="AckRequested"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" Name="CreateSequence"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" Name="Sequence"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="MessageID"/>
<sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" Name="SequenceAcknowledgement"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="Action"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="RelatesTo"/>
</sp:SignedParts>
<sp:Wss10>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:Wss10>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:BootstrapPolicy>
<sp:RequireDerivedKeys/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:SecureConversationToken>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:ProtectionToken>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:SymmetricBinding>
<sp:Trust13>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:MustSupportIssuedTokens/>
<sp:RequireClientEntropy/>
<sp:RequireServerEntropy/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:Trust13>
<sp:Wss11>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:MustSupportRefEncryptedKey/>
<sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
<sp:MustSupportRefThumbprint/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:Wss11>
<wsam:Addressing/>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702" wsu:Id="MusicAppDataPortBinding_getMusicFileData_Input_Policy">
<sp:EncryptedParts>
<sp:Body/>
</sp:EncryptedParts>
<sp:SignedParts>
<sp:Body/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="ReplyTo"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="To"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="From"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" Name="AckRequested"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" Name="CreateSequence"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" Name="Sequence"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="MessageID"/>
<sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" Name="SequenceAcknowledgement"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="Action"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="RelatesTo"/>
</sp:SignedParts>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702" wsu:Id="MusicAppDataPortBinding_getMusicFileData_Output_Policy">
<sp:EncryptedParts>
<sp:Body/>
</sp:EncryptedParts>
<sp:SignedParts>
<sp:Body/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="ReplyTo"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="To"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="From"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" Name="AckRequested"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" Name="CreateSequence"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" Name="Sequence"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="MessageID"/>
<sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" Name="SequenceAcknowledgement"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="Action"/>
<sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="RelatesTo"/>
</sp:SignedParts>
</wsp:Policy>
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://Musicpackage/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/MusicAppService/MusicAppDataService?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="getMusicFileData">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:getMusicFileData"/>
</message>
<message name="getMusicFileDataResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:getMusicFileDataResponse"/>
</message>
<portType name="MusicAppData">
<operation name="getMusicFileData">
<input wsam:Action="http://Musicpackage/MusicAppData/getMusicFileDataRequest" message="tns:getMusicFileData"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://Musicpackage/MusicAppData/getMusicFileDataResponse" message="tns:getMusicFileDataResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="MusicAppDataPortBinding" type="tns:MusicAppData">
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="#MusicAppDataPortBindingPolicy"/>
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<operation name="getMusicFileData">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="#MusicAppDataPortBinding_getMusicFileData_Input_Policy"/>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="#MusicAppDataPortBinding_getMusicFileData_Output_Policy"/>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="MusicAppDataService">
<port name="MusicAppDataPort" binding="tns:MusicAppDataPortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/MusicAppService/MusicAppDataService"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>**strong text****strong text**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Projects View, right-click the Web Application -> Web Services -> WebServiceNode

and

select "Edit Web Service Attributes" from list

UnCheck **Secure Service** checkBox

Click O.k and it Should work.

Check [Glen Mazza's Weblog](http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/metro_usernametoken_profile)

Answer (score 2):

You must have checked (or you did not unchecked) "use WS-Security" checkbox in NetBeans web services generator. This additional stuff you see in Java web service SOAP envelope is connected with WS-Security information.